# Simple MySQL SELECT Query AND Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Reviews table:

```
+--------------------+
| ID | DESC |  MISC  |
+--------------------+
| 1  | EDR  | NULL   | 
| 2  | EDR  | Mumba  | 
| 3  | EDR  | NULL   | 
| 4  | YTO  | Mumba  | 
| 5  | YTO  | Mumba  | 
+--------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Reviews
WHERE DESC = 'EDR' AND MISC <> 'Sent'
```

I'm expecting my query to return:

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
+----+
```

But instead, I get:

```
+------+
|  ID  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

What gives?

Comment: Your query returns ID = 2 and **not** NULL. Edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL` -- which is treated as `FALSE` -- even `<>`.

So, use a `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Reviews
WHERE DESC = 'EDR' AND NOT (MISC <=> 'Sent')
```

And, I'll point out that there is a standard `NULL`-safe comparison in SQL.  In your case, that would be:  `MISC IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'Sent'`.  But MySQL has its own syntax.

Comment: Is this an SQL quirk? In JavaScript and PHP, I'm used to comparing a value to null, e.g., $value != NULL // true

Comment: @GTSJoe . . . I would not call it a "quirk".  It is the definition of `NULL` in the SQL language.  Java and PHP were invented in 1995 and 1994 respectively.  SQL predates them by about 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

A value can't be equal to NULL, nor can it be different from NULL.

It's easier to understand if you see a NULL as 'unknown'.

But you can check with `IS NULL`

```
SELECT ID
FROM Reviews
WHERE DESC = 'EDR' 
AND (MISC IS NULL OR MISC <> 'Sent')
```